# Can "them" be used to indicate uncountable noun like "information"

Tags: grammar

I met this sentence:

"There's a lot of information regarding how to motivate yourself out there but most of them are not that effective."

"information" is a uncountable noun. Why in the latter sentence used most of "them" to indicated it?
If such usage is correct, why?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Answer (score 1):

No - *information* is **never** plural, and *them* always is.

See: https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2010/11/09/information/

(*Ideas* and *data* are examples of plural alternatives, although you might get away with using *data* as singular.)

Comment: In the quoted sentence, *them* is grammatically plural (' . . . **are** not that effective'). The problem is that its **antecedent** (*information*) is singular.  It should, however, be noted that many people, including many contributors to this site, passionately argue that it is OK to use *they* and related words with a singular antecedent, when one is talking about persons. If it is OK to use it that way when talking about persons, one may wonder why isn't it OK to so use it generally.

Comment: @jsw29 - *information* isn't singular either (no one asks for 'an information').  *They* is useful as a **genderless** non-neuter pronoun regardless of the quantity of the antecedent, but it remains in plural form ('they **are**'), and is comfortable to my ear only when it means '[the] one of them' (not a specific named person).

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answers and comments!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, "information" is AN (not "a" by the way) uncountable noun. So, you should say "but most of IT IS not that effective."

Comment: Thank you for your answer!